# jhipster 8080 blank page on windows

Tags: jhipster

I am generating a jhipster project with yoeman on the windows terminal. Everytime i try to generate a new project, i get a blank page on localhost:8080 when i run mvnw and yarn start.

Github link : https://github.com/Fosio/JALPlanning.git

Here is the build i am using :

```
    {
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.jalarue.jalplanning",
      "nativeLanguage": "fr"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.13.0",
    "baseName": "JALPlanning",
    "packageName": "com.jalarue.jalplanning",
    "packageFolder": "com/jalarue/jalplanning",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mssql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "73f9ef15682487a68491ce79f5c3352d0aa0aaab",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": false,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "cucumber",
      "protractor"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "fr",
    "languages": [
      "fr",
      "en"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have the following version of the requirement installed

node v9.3.0
yarn v1.3.2
Java 8

Here is the yarn start

```
Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\Simon Frenette\Documents\GitHub\JALPlanning>yarn start
yarn run v1.3.2
$ yarn run webpack:dev
$ yarn run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060 --watch-content-base
warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
$ node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060 --watch-content-base
 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active[HPM] Proxy created: [ '/api',
  '/management',
  '/swagger-resources',
  '/v2/api-docs',
  '/h2-console',
  '/auth' ]  ->  http://127.0.0.1:8080

Project is running at http://localhost:9060/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from ./target/www                                                                                                                                                                        11% building modules 11/17 modules 6 acti
ve ...modules\style-loader\lib\addStyles.jsWarning: The 'no-unused-variable' rule requires type infomation.

[at-loader] Using typescript@2.5.3 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from C:\Users\Simon Frenette\Documents\GitHub\JALPlanning/tsconfig.json.
                                                                                                                                                                                11558ms building modules
31ms sealing
0ms optimizing 
1ms basic module optimization 
36ms module optimization
1ms advanced module optimization 
28ms basic chunk optimization       
0ms chunk optimization 
0ms advanced chunk optimization 
5ms module and chunk tree optimization 
1ms chunk modules optimization 
0ms advanced chunk modules optimization 
73ms module reviving
11ms module order optimization
24ms module id optimization
5ms chunk reviving 
1ms chunk order optimization 
24ms chunk id optimization
37ms hashing
1ms module assets processing 
3756ms chunk assets processing
204ms additional chunk assets processing
1ms recording 
1ms additional asset processing 
0ms chunk asset optimization 
 94% asset optimization
[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...

[at-loader] Ok, 0.176 sec.
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin compilation started...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin compilation completed...                                                                                                                                                                                             299ms asset optimizatio
n
 95% emittingMergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit starts...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit completed...                                                                                                                                                                                                              304ms emittin
g
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit starts...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit completed...
Hash: 9f78c5679d4cae109731
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 16199ms
 43 assets
[./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css] ./node_modules/css-loader!./src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css 5.09 kB {3} [built]
       [] -> factory:269ms building:3900ms = 4169ms
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:9060] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 7.95 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:40ms building:29ms dependencies:497ms = 566ms
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.73 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:24ms building:774ms = 798ms
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:24ms building:769ms = 793ms
[./node_modules/webpack/hot ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:14ms building:9ms dependencies:848ms = 871ms
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.61 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:74ms building:14ms = 88ms
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:3ms building:769ms = 772ms
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/log-apply-result.js] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.31 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:853ms building:3534ms dependencies:0ms = 4387ms
[./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts 590 bytes {2} [built]
       [] -> factory:562ms building:3865ms = 4427ms
[./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts 2.63 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:302ms building:4140ms = 4442ms
[./src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css] ./src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css 1.05 kB {3} [built]
       [] -> factory:284ms building:15ms = 299ms
   [0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills 52 bytes {1} [built]
        factory:0ms building:2ms = 2ms
   [1] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css 52 bytes {3} [built]
        factory:0ms building:1ms dependencies:72ms = 73ms
   [2] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main 52 bytes {2} [built]
        factory:0ms building:0ms dependencies:72ms = 72ms
[./src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp] ./src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp 61 bytes {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:383ms dependencies:2ms building:753ms = 1138ms
    + 1042 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/index.html] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/index.html 883 bytes {0} [built]
            factory:101ms building:854ms = 955ms
webpack: Compiled successfully.
Hash: 9f78c5679d4cae109731
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 16588ms
 43 assets
[./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css] ./node_modules/css-loader!./src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css 5.09 kB {3} [built]
       [] -> factory:269ms building:3900ms = 4169ms
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:9060] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 7.95 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:40ms building:29ms dependencies:497ms = 566ms
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.73 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:24ms building:774ms = 798ms
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:24ms building:769ms = 793ms
[./node_modules/webpack/hot ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:14ms building:9ms dependencies:848ms = 871ms
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.61 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:74ms building:14ms = 88ms
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:3ms building:769ms = 772ms
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/log-apply-result.js] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.31 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:853ms building:3534ms dependencies:0ms = 4387ms
[./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts 590 bytes {2} [built]
       [] -> factory:562ms building:3865ms = 4427ms
[./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts 2.63 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:302ms building:4140ms = 4442ms
[./src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css] ./src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css 1.05 kB {3} [built]
       [] -> factory:284ms building:15ms = 299ms
   [0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills 52 bytes {1} [built]
        factory:0ms building:2ms = 2ms
   [1] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css 52 bytes {3} [built]
        factory:0ms building:1ms dependencies:72ms = 73ms
   [2] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main 52 bytes {2} [built]
        factory:0ms building:0ms dependencies:72ms = 72ms
[./src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp] ./src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp 61 bytes {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:383ms dependencies:2ms building:753ms = 1138ms
    + 1042 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/index.html] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/index.html 883 bytes {0} [built]
            factory:101ms building:854ms = 955ms
webpack: Compiled successfully.
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:9060
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:9000
    External: http://192.168.0.111:9000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.0.111:3001
 --------------------------------------
```

Here is the mvnw

```
C:\Users\Simon Frenette\Documents\GitHub\JALPlanning>mvn
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JAL Planning 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ jal-planning >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (default-resources) @ jal-planning ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 17 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ jal-planning ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 17 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ jal-planning ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (docker-resources) @ jal-planning ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ jal-planning ---
[INFO] argLine set to "-javaagent:C:\\Users\\Simon Frenette\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.9\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Users\\Simon Frenette\\Documents\\GitHub\\JALPlanning\\target\\test-results\\coverage\\jacoco\\ja
coco.exec" -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ jal-planning ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 78 source files to C:\Users\Simon Frenette\Documents\GitHub\JALPlanning\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ jal-planning ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jal-planning ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ jal-planning <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ jal-planning ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\Simon Frenette\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/Simon%20Frenette/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3
.5.3/lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar
11:33:06.583 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
11:33:06.585 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/
, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
11:33:06.585 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/Users/Simon%20Frenette/Documents/GitHub/JALPlanning/target/classes/]

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE ::
:: http://www.jhipster.tech ::

2017-12-17 11:33:07.438  INFO 6324 --- [  restartedMain] com.jalarue.jalplanning.JalPlanningApp   : Starting JalPlanningApp on SimonFrenette with PID 6324 (started by Simon Frenette in C:\Users\Simon Frenette\Documents\GitHub\JALPlanning)
2017-12-17 11:33:07.439 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] com.jalarue.jalplanning.JalPlanningApp   : Running with Spring Boot v1.5.9.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.13.RELEASE
2017-12-17 11:33:07.439  INFO 6324 --- [  restartedMain] com.jalarue.jalplanning.JalPlanningApp   : The following profiles are active: swagger,dev
2017-12-17 11:33:07.663 DEBUG 6324 --- [kground-preinit] org.jboss.logging                        : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property
2017-12-17 11:33:09.670 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.j.config.AsyncConfiguration          : Creating Async Task Executor
2017-12-17 11:33:10.365 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] class org.ehcache.core.Ehcache-users     : Initialize successful.
2017-12-17 11:33:10.374 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.jalarue.jalplanning.domain.User  : Initialize successful.
2017-12-17 11:33:10.377 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.j.jalplanning.domain.Authority   : Initialize successful.
2017-12-17 11:33:10.383 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.j.j.domain.User.authorities      : Initialize successful.
2017-12-17 11:33:10.612 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.j.config.MetricsConfiguration        : Registering JVM gauges
2017-12-17 11:33:10.627 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.j.config.MetricsConfiguration        : Monitoring the datasource
2017-12-17 11:33:10.627 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.j.config.MetricsConfiguration        : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2017-12-17 11:33:11.349 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.jalplanning.config.WebConfigurer     : Registering CORS filter
2017-12-17 11:33:11.474  INFO 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.jalplanning.config.WebConfigurer     : Web application configuration, using profiles: swagger
2017-12-17 11:33:11.475 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.jalplanning.config.WebConfigurer     : Initializing Metrics registries
2017-12-17 11:33:11.479 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.jalplanning.config.WebConfigurer     : Registering Metrics Filter
2017-12-17 11:33:11.480 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.jalplanning.config.WebConfigurer     : Registering Metrics Servlet
2017-12-17 11:33:11.483 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.jalplanning.config.WebConfigurer     : Initialize H2 console
2017-12-17 11:33:11.484  INFO 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.jalplanning.config.WebConfigurer     : Web application fully configured
2017-12-17 11:33:11.746 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.j.config.DatabaseConfiguration       : Configuring Liquibase
2017-12-17 11:33:11.761  WARN 6324 --- [ning-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2017-12-17 11:33:12.772 DEBUG 6324 --- [ning-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase has updated your database in 1010 ms
2017-12-17 11:33:19.682 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Starting Swagger
2017-12-17 11:33:19.689 DEBUG 6324 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Started Swagger in 6 ms
2017-12-17 11:33:20.763  INFO 6324 --- [  restartedMain] com.jalarue.jalplanning.JalPlanningApp   : Started JalPlanningApp in 14.159 seconds (JVM running for 14.612)
2017-12-17 11:33:20.764  INFO 6324 --- [  restartedMain] com.jalarue.jalplanning.JalPlanningApp   :
----------------------------------------------------------
        Application 'JALPlanning' is running! Access URLs:
        Local:          http://localhost:8080
        External:       http://192.168.0.111:8080
        Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be appreciated

Regards

Simon

Comment: Any error during start? Does altering the port help?

Comment: I edited my main message to include yarn start and mvn. It doesnt change anything to alter the port

Comment: Have you tried on different browsers ?

Comment: Yes, i doesnt work either.

Comment: No error in browser console? Why navigating to port 8080, you're supposed to go to webpack dev server on port 9000.

Comment: There are no error on the chrome console on the localhost:8080. The register email content use the port 8080 to register a new user... When i click the registerlink it open the localhost:8080, but then nothing append.http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/activate?key=70203405475019037188

Comment: Yes but as I said you're supposed to access port 9000 in dev for hot reload. Now if you want to use port 8080 to test user registration, you must build frontend first with `yarn run webpack:build` before running `mvnw` as explained in the doc: http://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/

Comment: Gaël, yes i am aware that i need to build the webpack before runing the mvn. However, even i do so, the localhost:8080 is blank and i could not test the user registration

Comment: Check source of index.html. Sometimes I have it blank and have to recover it from previous commits.

Comment: Every project i generate are like that... When i generate a project on my mac, everything is fine.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, I have looked everywhere for solutions on stackoverflow. Nothing has helped.

Comment: Chol, I had to reformat my computer for other reason, and it resolved the issue...